# Asked a Question with "bugs" as tag, but my "tags" tab is showing "You have not participated in any tags"

Tags: support, tag-score

Asked a Question with "bugs" as tag, but my "tags" tab is showing  "You have not participated in any tags".

Please see attached image for details.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just asked that question 20 minutes ago. Your tag scores are only calculated **once daily** at 03:00 UTC. You'll have to wait until the scores get updated to see anything there.

Comment: my earlier question is regarding tags with votes in Stack Overflow profile and **talking about votes caste few days ago**. but the least question is regarding meta profile.

Comment: @vikas Stack Overflow is a special case where the query that updates them is failing often and not updating. In *this* case, here on Meta, you just have to wait.

Comment: @animuson will my earlier question be considered as bug?

Comment: Yes. When the update script runs at 03:00, the [tag:bug] tag will appear there with a score of 0 beside it (because votes on questions don't affect your tag score, only votes on answers).